# Accessing host data modified by docker container

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to use docker on my local system for development purposes.

I have added volume to get the code updated from docker container in docker-compose file

```
volumes:   
    - home/user/myproject:/myproject
```

I am using Django Framework and with docker, I added some apps.

`docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID python3 manage.py startapp myapp`

This adds an app to my host as well. But it is readonly.

How can I change the permission to make it executable and writable from my host as well?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question but, maybe you are talking about volumes in Docker?

Comment: yes added volume for the project directory. i have added following in docker-compose file.

`volumes:
      - "/home/projects/my_project:/myproject"`

Comment: And did it solve your problem?

Comment: it does update the code, but i cant write anything. it is read only.

Comment: Would a Python virtual environment, without Docker, be easier to manage here?  You don't need a special tool or config file to run it, and it will be able to directly access files on the host system without any particular setup.

Comment: @DavidMaze, yes it surely would. just trying things out with docker :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.